# Modal UITableView dialog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Is there an option to show a modal dialog containing uitableview in the middle of the screen with size 200x200 whyle all other parts of parent screen are darken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the iPhone, you can't do this using the standard way of presenting modal dialog controllers, because it is assumed your modal dialog will cover the old content entirely, and the old content isn't painted underneath your modal (so making your modal dialog partly transparent wouldn't help).

One approach to get the effect is to augment the currently showing view by adding a UIView as a subview in the centre of the screen (for your actual modal content), complete with another layer underneath with partial transparency and black colour to cause the 'underneath' UI to appear darker.

See also this related question/answer: [Transparency for top UIView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246517/transparency-for-top-uiview-not-working/5246615#5246615)

Comment: Ok. This worked, however my table view gets alpha of its parent view. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIView with your desired coordinate and size and make table view fited on this.

then add that as a subview on the view. some thing like this.

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,200)];

UITableView *tbl=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,200)];

tbl.delegate=self;
tbl.dataSource=self;
[view addSubView:tbl];
[self.view addSubView:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, why not? Create a new UIViewController and embed your uitableview in it. You'll have to do some custom drawing of the view, maybe adding an additional black uiview with maybe 50% transparancy as the backbround, and positioning the tableview as you like on top of it.

Use presentModalViewController:animated on the current uiviewcontroller which should be blocked by the new modal view finally.